# strange characters when redirecting to file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script that contains lines:

```
remote_installer_svc_args="$local_cifs_mount/eset-remote-installer.args"    
svc_arg_x86="%SYSTEMROOT%\\$(basename $remote_temp_dir)\\$(basename $INSTALLER_BAT)"
svc_arg_x64="%SYSTEMROOT%\\$(basename $remote_temp_dir)\\$(basename $INSTALLER_BAT)"
echo "$svc_arg_x86" > $remote_installer_svc_args
echo "$svc_arg_x64" >> $remote_installer_svc_args
```

It should produce a file that looks like this (in notepad++ on windows):
[image]

instead the file looks like this:
[image]

or in vim:
[image]

What is wrong with the script? Because when I copy those lines into bash it works, only if I run the script it does produce those strange characters...

Comment: The script is not recorded. It is written in a file by hand. Then when it is executed, it causes the problem. WhenI open the sh file in text editor, copy the lines and paste them into terminal, it works as it should.

Comment: What does `$(basename $remote_temp_dir)` expand to?

Comment: How do you run the script? Does the script begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into part of the mess of inconsistent behavior that plagues the `echo` command. Specifically, some versions of `echo` (in some modes) interpret escape (backslash) sequences in the string they're asked to print. Others don't. When you ask `echo` to print `%SYSTEMROOT%\era_rd_6HbUKJTR\EraAgentInstaller.bat`, it *might* see the `\e` part and think it's supposed to convert that to the [ASCII escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).

Note that there are two different characters being called "escape" here: The backslash is used by the shell as an escape character, meaning that it and the characters immediately following it have some special meaning. The ASCII escape, on the other hand, is treated as a special character by the terminal (and vim and some other things) in a somewhat similar manner. Since the ASCII escape is a nonprinting character, when notepad++ and vim have to display it, they show some sort of alternate representation ("ESC" or "^]").

Anyway, since `echo` is inconsistent about its treatment of the backslash character, it's best to avoid it for strings that might contain backslash. Use `printf` instead (see ["Why is printf better than echo?" on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)). It's a little more complicated to use, but not too bad. The main things to realize are that the first argument to `printf` is a "format" string that's used to control how the rest of the arguments are printed, and that unlike `echo` it doesn't automatically add a newline to the end.

What you want to use is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$svc_arg_x86" > $remote_installer_svc_args
printf '%s\n' "$svc_arg_x64" >> $remote_installer_svc_args
```

Or you can simplify it to:

```
printf '%s\n' "$svc_arg_x86" "$svc_arg_x64" > $remote_installer_svc_args
```

That first argument, `%s\n`, says to print a plain string followed by a newline. Backslash escapes in the format string are *always* interpreted, but strings formatted with the `%s` format *never* have escapes interpreted. Note that in the single-command version, the format string gets applied to each of the other two arguments, so each gets a newline at the end, so each winds up on a separate line in the output file.